# UISplitViewController with iOS 11 large titles broken animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

When using the UISplitViewController in navigating from Master to Detail the navigation bar animation does not work as expected. It "jumps" up instead of a smooth animation.

Steps to Reproduce:
Create project from template "Master detail App" in Xcode 9.
Add the following code into `MasterViewController` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

Add the following code in `DetailViewController` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

Now navigate between Master and Detail in the iPhone simulator and you can see how the Navigation Bar "jumps" up on the DetailViewController instead of a smooth animation.

See video:  https://youtu.be/p90I4VrM2fs

My assumption is that it has something to do with using two UINavigationController with the UISplitViewController. (which is how it is done)

[image]

Any ideas how to resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the problem. `prefersLargeTitles` and `largeTitleDisplayMode` have to be set in `awakeFromNib()`, not in `viewDidLoad()`.